# When I upload basic code to NodeMCU showing an compiling error

Tags: python, windows, compiler-errors, arduino, nodemcu

I'm using Windows 10. I want to upload some basic code to my NodeMCU module.

Code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(D0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  digitalWrite(D0, HIGH);
}
```

But when it's compiling Showing this error.

```
exec: "{runtime.tools.python.path}/python": file does not exist
Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).
```

What should I do for this error?

Comment: Looks like your build process requires Python to be installed and on the PATH.

Comment: I don't know how to add it.

Comment: Did you install Arduino IDE as documented here https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing.html ?

Comment: I reset my PC..